# is there a way to reduce the css transition jumpiness of bookblock.js

Tags: javascript, css, bookblock

I'm currently facing a visual annoyance using the [bookblock.js plugin](https://github.com/codrops/BookBlock)

The website I'm referring to is:
http://indiewhip.com/projects/pulse.html

The page turn effect is cool, but very jittery. By Jittery, I mean that it jumps frames turning the page when loading the video or image.

I was wondering if anyone had any fixes, or resources I could use in attempt to achieve a more elegant effect?

all help and advice is greatly appreciated!